# Is it secure to use proxychains+Tor while logged in as root?

Tags: anonymity, linux

when using proxychains+Tor in kali,you should  be logged in as root because proxychanis doesn't work when you are not logged in as root but using Tor while logged in as root is not secure so what is the correct way of using proxychains+Tor,is it even possible to use these while you are not root?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using proxychains while logged in as root is also not secure and there's no reason you should have to give proxychains root access.

For example, the following works just fine for me without root:

```
$ PROXYCHAINS_SOCKS5=9050 telnet towel.blinkenlights.nl
```

Comment: I wonder : Are the root privileges only needed to be able to use ports under 1024?

Comment: @IrvingPoe Yes; that's a kernel level restriction.